# Appending session data to automatic Cake error/debug logs

Tags: php, cakephp, logging

CakePHP outputs simple log messages for events like PHP Notices/Errors if logging is on, and I was wondering if there was any way to set up Cake to automatically output extra info with the PHP error test; I'm specifically after Session information. If I could get the User ID it'd be a big help in debugging.

To clarify, these are the logs you get with `core.php` set to

```
Configure::write('log', true);
```

I know I can make my own logs which could then include the info I need, but I'd like to append the default PHP error messages to catch bugs I *don't* know about, if possible. Just something like dumping the `$_SESSION` array to my log would be a start but I don't know if this is possible.

I'm using Cake 2.2.2 and I'm *not* using the AuthComponent for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to create a different log instead using error log, but if you want to use the error log that's your deal.
To write the $_SESSION on error log, it's so simple, just write the following code wherever you want it

```
$this->log($_SESSION,'error');
```

It worked for me

[image]

You can keep using the error log to save everything you want